# Validator does not work in Django Rest Framework, why?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The Django Rest Framework Documentation sates [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation):

> Validators
>
> Individual fields on a serializer can include validators, by declaring
>   them on the field instance, for example:

But when I try to do this:

```
class DetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    name = serializers.Field(validators=[character_validator])

 class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("id", "name")
```

I get the following error:

```
   name = serializers.Field(validators=[character_validator])
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'validators'
```

Comment: The link you posted says that you need to declare the `validator` as a function, and not a `Field argument.`

Comment: @AronYsidoro yep then it also says: "Individual fields on a serializer can include validators, by declaring them on the field instance, for example"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Field Class you will notice it does not take 'validators', but `CharField`, `IntegerField` etc does.

Try:

```
serializers.CharField(validators=[character_validator])
```